# JQuery Ajax JSON error reporting on $.ajax post success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**EDIT: I fixed the errors with the PHP that have been mentioned in Answers but I still have the same problem.**

I'm trying to display an error message if my POST request fails, and to show a success message if it doesn't fail. It currently shows the success message correctly, but nothing happens if I make the sql fail, even in console.

JQUERY: // I have removed unnecessary code

```
        $("#form").validate({
        ignore:'',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent()); // <- make sure the error message appears after parent element (after textbox!)
        },
        rules: {
        },
        messages: {
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
            var datastring = $("#form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myscript.php",
            data: datastring,
            dataType:"json",
            success:  function (response) {
                if(response.status === "success") {
                    window.alert(response.comment);
                } else if(response.status === "error") {
                    window.alert(response.comment);
                }
             }
        }); // close $.ajax
    } // close submit handler 
}); //end validate
```

PHP:

```
    if($row = sasql_fetch_array($insert))
{   
    //success message 
    $arr = array ('status'=>'success','comment'=> $custid );
    echo json_encode($arr);


}  else {
    //error message
    $arr = array ('status'=>'error','comment'=>'There has been an error. Please try again.');
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what the issue could be here? Like I said, if I add `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` just after the `success` function, nothing at all is returned on the error array. Thanks

Comment: that is the response from the server, when you make an ajax call?

Comment: yes - for the success, if the sql fails though I get no response.

Comment: are you using `+` for string concatenation? It should be `.` (This is at `Please try again.'+$custid`)

Comment: remove `}` before else

Comment: @Mudaser Ali that gives me an error message...

Comment: there is an extra `}` before else `}

}  else {` what is the error can you please print it and for string concatination please use `.` instead of `+`

Comment: @Ninsly even removing the `'+$custid` makes no difference...

Comment: @Janey i had posted the php code with correction there are 2 errors in your php code. please use it and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your php file. You got syntax error in failure part. But not in success. You used unwanted } and concatenate string using + instead of . operator. Also remove the empty spaces near the array.

```
    if($row = sasql_fetch_array($insert))
{   
    //success message 
    $arr = array ('status'=>'success','comment'=> $custid );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}

}  else {
    //error message
    $arr = array ('status'=>'error','comment'=>'There has been an error. Please try again.'+$custid);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

should be

```
    if($row = sasql_fetch_array($insert))
{   
    //success message 
    $arr = array('status'=>'success','comment'=> $custid );
    echo json_encode($arr);

}  else {
    //error message
    $arr = array('status'=>'error','comment'=>'There has been an error. Please try again.'.$custid);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment... I fixed this and there is still nothing returned on error...!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this line:

```
$arr = array ('status'=>'error','comment'=>'There has been an error. Please try again.'+$custid);
```

You'll see that you're using `+` instead `.`, which is the [concatenation operator in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

it is the correct php code

```
if($row = sasql_fetch_array($insert))
{   
    //success message 
    $arr = array ('status'=>'success','comment'=> $custid );
    echo json_encode($arr);

}  else {
    //error message
    $arr = array ('status'=>'error','comment'=>'There has been an error. Please try again.' . $custid);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: then there might be an error before this condition; so need to debug your script before these lines